# Maximum string Parameter length in json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

what is maximum length of string parameter that can be passed by ajax to web method. Is there any limit for parameter value length?

Comment: you should know about `get and post` types.

Comment: For GET =1024 POST= unlimited

Comment: okay then i should use POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using a GET request there's a limit which will depend on the client   browser. And this limit has nothing to do with AJAX. IIRC it was around 4K for IE but things might have changed. But in any case there's a limit. If you don't want to be limited you should use POST.